Trigger won't fire in MySQL database
I'm new to MySQL and creating a database for an assessed project. As part of that, I need to create a trigger and demonstrate how it works as part of that.
Schools in the DB belong to a group called a cluster (cluster_no: A, B, C or D) and attend sessions (1-6). There is a table called 'clusters' which contains information about who runs the cluster sessions, where they're held and whether the attendance register has been completed. The table 'cluster attendance record' contains the register of attendance at the sessions.
The records for sessions 1-3 are complete in the 'cluster attendance record' and I've created the trigger to add a statement to the table 'clusters' when the 'cluster attendance record' is updated for future sessions. The idea would be that after a cluster session has run I would know who has attended and can update the record for each school in 'cluster attendance record'. These are BOOLEAN values and set to 0 for sessions 4-6 as I have a view that calculates %attendance which doesn't work with NULL.
I've had to set it up so there is a different trigger for each cluster_no at each session (sessions 4-6) but when I've updated the record for cluster_id 1, session_4, nothing changed in the 'clusters' table as I was expecting.
Clusters table:

Cluster attendance record:

Code for update (which definitely works as I've tried it without the trigger)
UPDATE cluster_attendance_record
SET session_4 = 1 WHERE school_id IN ('S01', 'S02', 'S03', 'S05');

Code for trigger:
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER cA_s4_register_status
AFTER UPDATE
ON cluster_attendance_record 
FOR EACH ROW IF new.session_4 = 1 AND cluster_id = 'A'
THEN
    UPDATE clusters SET new.session_4 = 'REGISTER COMPLETE' 
    WHERE cluster_id = 'A';
END IF;
//
DELIMITER ;


school_id = 'S01' AND school_id ='S02' AND  school_id = 'S03' AND school_id ='S05'; school id can never be all 4 values you need ORs instead but safer to use IN

Your trigger will renew the values in ALL rows with cluster_no = 1, despite another columns values. Are you sure that you need in this? I think that you'd add additional conditions which will clarify the row to be updated, for example, .. AND school_id = NEW.school_id

'records for sessions 1-3 are complete in the 'cluster attendance record' - It doesn't look like it to me in the published date.  I would have expected that all rows for column sessions1-3 to be set to 1 for that to be true and for clusters to be set register complete when it is true. also it's more useful if you publish sample data as text.

Thank you @P.Salmon - have now changed to IN. 0 in the attendnace record means they didn't attend so that's why some session 1-3 show this. I'm not sure how to publish sample data as text. Last time I did that it was very long winded and I'm sure there's a quicker way - I just don't know it

When you say
IF cluster_no = 1

you just need to clarify that it's the new, updated value that you're referring to in the trigger definition.
You can do that like this:
FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.cluster_no = 1

Complete working example:
create table cluster_attendance_record (cluster_no int);
create table clusters (cluster_no integer, session_4 varchar(30));

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER c1_s4_register_status
AFTER UPDATE
ON cluster_attendance_record 
FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.cluster_no = 1
THEN
    UPDATE clusters SET session_4 = 'REGISTER COMPLETE' 
    WHERE cluster_no = 1;
END IF;
//
DELIMITER ;


insert into cluster_attendance_record (cluster_no)
select 0;

insert into clusters (cluster_no, session_4)
select 1, "some_value";

update cluster_attendance_record set cluster_no = 1;

select * from cluster_attendance_record;
select * from clusters;

Here's the dbfiddle.

I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work - see amended code in original question. I'm now a bit lost as I can get the UPDATE to work without the trigger but when the trigger is there I get an error: Error Code: 4048. Invalid target for assignment in INSERT or UPDATE statement 'NEW.session_4'.

I've added a link to the db fiddle so you can try out my working example. I see that you've incorporated my advice into your current question, which seems to have shifted a bit since the last edit.

@cyal7 I've got an alternative dbfiddle ready for you to try out. This one reflects some of the recent changes you've made to the question. Let me know if it helps and I can adjust my answer
